# Text on PShape Objects [processing]

Tags: processing, rect

How to write text on PShapes like rectangle /rect() in processing.org?? I am facing problem because normal text() function doesn't work and gets overshadowed by the shapes drawn afterwards,i want to write on a particular rectangle or ellipse like shape in processing 2.2.1??

Comment: Could you please post code that shows the problem that you want solved?

Comment: things are draw in the order of execution, so if the text call comes after the shape cal it should be visible. But as @kevinsa5 said, show some code for a better help... :)

Comment: this link  is the real struggle ,it would be great if you can help ,just go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296494/knights-tour-gui-in-processing